# One large table vs Large + cache table

Tags: mysql, triggers, large-data

I have *large* MySQL table (200K+ records). From this table, I mostly read last +-1000 records. To this table, I insert about 500 records / day.
My question. Should I use this one table and read from it or should I use one smaller table, used as cache.

What my cache table means: Every insert to *large* table will start trigger, that copy data to *"cache"* table and remove old ones (to keep size in range of max. 1000 records). Now, if I read something, I primary search in *"cache"* for "last entry records". Is user want to read "archive" data, I read from *large* table.

Is this good solution, or performance will be impacted by running trigger and deleting from *cache* table ? Or.. will be there any difference at all ?

SQL queries I mostly run consist of `SELECT`s with two `JOIN`s and searching results in range (using `HAVING` clause). I am using MyISAM DB engine.

Comment: If you have indexes for your joins, so you prevent full table scans, your cache table will only add overhead to inserts/updates but won't influence selects significantly.

Comment: Yes. I have indexes on columns that are compared or JOINed over.

Answer (score 1):

You can check that yourself - create a second table, using

```
create table cache as select * from orig_table order by insertiontime desc limit 1000
```

then add the same indexes to the cache table that the original table has, and do a few selects on the original table, and the same selects on the cache table. Measure the time in each case.

If you have proper indexes, and your result set size is the same (i.e. you don't select all the old records from the original table that the cache table doesn't have), the time difference shouldn't be more than a few percent.

It might help to do an [analyze table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/analyze-table.html) once a day, to prevent mysql from getting strange ideas about key distribution and using a sub-optimal join order.

If you want to exclude old records that you can't prevent your original join from selecting, you might want to read about [partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html), which does a similar thing to your cache idea but is implemented in the database engine.